# Memory issues/leaks in AES encryption/decryption of strings in java

Tags: java, string, encryption

My problem is that I am decrypting/encrypting some string sets of random values from different threads but after many iterations the memory increases rapidly.
My observation is that memory increases because each encryption/decryption result in new String and due to it the memory increases.
**One more point to note is that** my decrypted/encrypted strings would be having so many same values as same sets of strings (some strings might be new) are encrypted/decrypted from many thread but since in each encrpt/decrypt the cipher returns the byte array and to constitute the String again I have to use 'new String()' function and this might or will increase memory rapidly.
This is my code to encrypt/decrypt strings

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String value) throws GeneralSecurityException 
{

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes();
    if (raw.length != 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    byte[] cipherBytes= cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    byte[] encoded =    org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(cipherBytes);
    return new String(encoded);

}

public static String decrypt(String key, String encrypted) throws GeneralSecurityException 
{

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes();
    if (raw.length != 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    byte[] byteDecodedText =  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted.getBytes()) ;

    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(byteDecodedText);

    return new String(original);
}
```

Comment: You could call `intern()` on the `String` as soon as you've extracted it from the byte array, and drop all references to the `String`.  The `String` will take up memory until it's garbage collected, of course, but I can't see how you could do better than this.

Comment: @DavidWallace it means I have to call intern on new String(byteDecryptedText);

Comment: Yes, obviously.  But you're going to have to call `new String(byteDecryptedText)` at some point anyway.

Comment: @DavidWallace I did that but no improvement same memory spike.

Comment: Yes, but did the spike go away after garbage collection?

Comment: My only other idea would be to wrap the `byte[]` in some kind of object, and set up a `Map` of some kind, mapping your byte array wrapper class to `String`.

Comment: @DavidWallace no the memory was high after calling System.gc() also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38872/discussion-between-dbw-and-david-wallace)

Comment: Let's not continue this discussion in chat.  It's 1am.  I need to go to sleep.  Maybe someone else can help you.  Or you can wait till I wake up.

Comment: There is a *major* problem here. You shouldn't be storing the cipher text in a String. String is not a container for binary data. Use the byte[] array returned by doFinal() directly.

Comment: @EJP byte[] array returned in both the encrypt decrypt function but if I want to access the string values how could I achieve it

Comment: You don't want to access encrypted ciphertext as a string at all. It isn't a string. It's binary. You're committing a category mistake, or a type error.

Comment: What about decryption I need to have decrypted value at some moment... let us continue [the discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38872/discussion-between-dbw-and-david-wallace)

Comment: Certainly. I haven't said a word about that. I am talking about ciphertext, not plaintext.

Answer (score 3):

String intern method is probably is the way to go. It returns canonical representation of the string, so for to identical strings you will have only one instance.
So when you return a String, just try to do:

```
 new String(byteDecryptedText).intern();
```

an instance of the String that you create by using new will be collected after you get out of the scope. Internal object will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for reply but it did not solved the problem as when we call new String(byteDecryptedText) a new String in heap will already be created

Comment: yes, and it will be collected by gc after you return from the function which I think is ok because there is no reference to that instance. So the total heap size will grow only accordingly to the unique strings

Comment: let us [continue the discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38872/discussion-between-dbw-and-david-wallace)

Comment: there was no improvement after assigning this code, the memory went on increasing as it was increasing earlier

Comment: That probably because all strings that are produced by those two functions are unique. Are you sure that majority of generated Strings has exactly the same content?

Comment: @dbw Hard to see how they won't be unique, given that you using new keys each time. Your code doesn't actually work as posted.

Comment: @FedorSkrynnikov yes the majority of strings that are generated have the same contents as I am reading those values from database everytime and I have always to query database if there are some changes.

Comment: @EJP sorry I was just quoting an example the password used to encrypt decrypt string is always the same

Comment: @EJP I have edited my post with new working code may be it could help

Answer (score 1):

It is true that each iteration will result in new String but I do not think that will increase memory very rapidly as the memory required by a String is in bytes.
According to [String memory usage](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml) you can calculate size of String you encrypt or decrypt. This can provide you some idea whether memory increased is due to formation of new String everytime.

Comment: valid point, now to look into issue with some different perspective